# Oracle: Convert Full Date to a Different Date Format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In my Oracle database,I have a column of type VARCHAR2 in a table that has entry like this:

```
Wednesday, August 3, 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST
```

I wish to convert it to something like `08-03-2016`

I have tried to use TO_DATE followed by TO_CHAR but it fails. Some guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use SUBSTR & INSTR

e.g:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
 SUBSTR(SUBSTR(date_str,1,INSTR(date_str,',',-1)-1),INSTR(SUBSTR(date_str,1,INSTR(date_str,',',-1)-1) ,' ',-1))
  || SUBSTR(date_str,INSTR(date_str,',')+2,3)
  || SUBSTR(date_str,-21,4) ,'DDMONYYYY')
FROM
  ( SELECT 'Wednesday, August 23, 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST' AS date_str FROM dual )
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(date_str,1, INSTR(date_str,',',-1)+5) ,'DAY, MONTH DD, YYYY') 
  FROM (
  SELECT 'Wednesday, August 3, 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST' AS date_str FROM dual
  )
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks! What if the value of the long date was in date format itself?

Comment: depends what you are doing with it, if you want to display the date in a specific format simply cast to a string using to_char

Comment: I tried doing that but it Oracle does not seem to like it. I just did SELECT TO_CHAR(Date_column, 'MM-DD-YY') from dual;

Comment: sorry this is a different question ;)

Comment: I am happy to post another question ;) Or you can be kind enough to answer it here :)

Comment: nope, you need another question, where you can show the column type,  the contents of the column, the error you get what you have tried so far etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR('Wednesday, August 3, 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST', 
           '\w+ +\d+, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (A|P)M'), 
        'fmMonth DD, fmYYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
FROM dual;
```

resp.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
    TO_TIMESTAMP(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR('Wednesday, August 3, 2016 12:00:00 AM CEST', 
           '\w+ +\d+, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (A|P)M'), 
        'fmMonth DD, fmYYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 
    'MM-DD-YYYY')
FROM dual;
```

In case you need only the day but no time information you had good luck, because `CEST` is ambiguous, see this:

```
SELECT TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME), TZNAME
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZABBREV = 'CEST'
ORDER BY 2;

TZABBREV TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)  TZNAME
======== ================== ============
CEST    +01:00  Africa/Algiers
CEST    +01:00  Europe/Lisbon
CEST    +01:00  Portugal
CEST    +02:00  Atlantic/Jan_Mayen
CEST    +02:00  CET
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Amsterdam
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Belgrade
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Berlin
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Bratislava
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Brussels
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Budapest
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Copenhagen
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Gibraltar
CEST    +02:00  Arctic/Longyearbyen
CEST    +02:00  Africa/Tunis
CEST    +02:00  Africa/Tripoli
CEST    +02:00  Africa/Ceuta
CEST    +02:00  Poland
CEST    +02:00  Libya
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Zurich
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Zagreb
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Warsaw
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Vienna
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Vatican
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Tirane
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Ljubljana
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Luxembourg
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Madrid
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Monaco
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Oslo
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Paris
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Podgorica
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Prague
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Rome
CEST    +02:00  Europe/San_Marino
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Sarajevo
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Skopje
CEST    +02:00  Europe/Stockholm
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Zaporozhye
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Tallinn
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Vilnius
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Minsk
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Kaliningrad
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Sofia
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Uzhgorod
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Athens
CEST    +03:00  Europe/Riga
```

Thus it is not trivial to determine the correct time zone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few separate problems (aside from storing timestamps with time zone in a VARCHAR2 column, which is wrong to begin with).

One is that CEST is not "pre-installed" (not in my installation of Oracle at least; CEST is not recognized). You will have to rely on a specific time zone file. For illustration I will use EST instead (US/East Coast).

Then, you need to be able to convert a character string into a timestamp with time zone. You can do that like so:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('Thursday, July 28, 2016 09:16:15 AM EST',
                        'Day, Month dd, yyyy, hh:mi:ss AM tzr') as ts from dual;



TS
---------------------------------------
28-JUL-16 09.16.15.000000000 AM EST
```

At this point, `TS` is a timestamp; what is displayed on the screen is dictated by my session's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` parameter. By the way, this assumes that your `NLS_LANGUAGE` is set to `'American'`, otherwise the conversion of `'Thursday'` will not work; you will need to add the `nls_param` parameter to `to_timestamp_tz()`.

Then, if you need to display the result as `'07-28-2016'`, you can wrap the whole monster within `to_char(..., 'mm-dd-yyyy')`.

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('Thursday, July 28, 2016 09:16:15 AM EST',
                  'Day, Month dd, yyyy, hh:mi:ss AM tzr'), 'mm-dd-yyyy') as ts from dual;



TS
----------
07-28-2016
```